# Solve a Non-linear Equation of one variable but written in a summation form, in "R"

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions

[image: This is the Non-Linear Equation in "mu" which I want to solve numerically using R. All of the paired (x, y) are known. So the only variable is "mu".]

This is the Non-Linear Equation in "mu" which I want to solve numerically using R. All of the paired (x, y) are known. So the only variable is "mu"

Now, I have written the function in R. Then, I am trying to get the root by using "rootSolve" package. But it is giving an error.

This is my code of the function:

```
f = function(k){
sum(((2*exp(-x) - 1)*(2*exp(-y)- 1))/
    (1 + k*(2*exp(-x) - 1)*(2*exp(-y)- 1)))
}
```

This is the error after running "uniroot.all" from the "rootSolve" package:

```
> library(rootSolve)
> uniroot.all(f, interval = c(-1, 1))
numeric(0)
Warning message:
In k * (2 * exp(-x) - 1) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Also, I am searching my root in the interval (-1, 1).

Can someone please help? I think, my way of defining the function is wrong. Hence this error is coming.

Can anyone confirm that my way of defining the function in the picture is correct or not?

Thank you in advance!

#### Let me add something more:

The way I have defined my function (chances are high that the way is wrong) and given my data `(x, y)`, I have `f(-1) < f(1) and also f(-1) * f(1) < 0`. These conditions are satisfied.

#### Additional Problem that makes me question my way of writing the function:

I cannot run curve function in `R`. e.g., `curve(f, from = -1, to = 1)`
But, if I plot `Vectorize(f)`, then the `curve` function works.

***Can anyone please help me in correcting the way of defining the function?***

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are not showing all. What are the values of `x` and `y`?

Comment: You seem to have `mu` and `x` mixed up. You want to solve for `mu` so specify it in the function (also as an argument of the function).

Comment: @Bhas, I have edited. I hope things are clear now. I have biavriate data on (x, y). A total of almost 1000 observations.

Comment: We don't have your `x` and `y` data. So we can't run your stuff. It is not reproducible. Make a small set of data and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `uniroot.all` wants a vectorized function. I have tried to use it and get the same error as you do. I can't find anything in the documentation of `uniroot.all` about this.

I have tried package `nleqslv` and can get a solution.
I have rewritten your function as follows (I think you made some errors in setting up the equation):

```
f <- function(k){
    A <- 2*exp(-x)-1
    B <- 2*exp(-y)-1
    sum((A*B)/(1+k*A*B))
}
```

and run the function with these data

```
set.seed(13)
x <- runif(10)*10
y <- runif(10)*5
```

and the solved your function as follows:

```
library(nleqslv)
nleqslv(0,f)
```

with the following output:

```
$x
[1] 1.42992

$fvec
[1] 2.300633e-09

$termcd
[1] 1

$message
[1] "Function criterion near zero"

$scalex
[1] 1

$nfcnt
[1] 7

$njcnt
[1] 1

$iter
[1] 7
```

This solves with a Secant method. If you want to try other methods you can use `testnslv` to explore.

** Addition **

Function `uniroot.all` will work in my example as long as you do:

```
fvec <- Vectorize(f)
```

and change the interval to `c(-1,1.7)`.

Comment: Bhas, Thank you very much for your help! I appreciate it a lot. Actually, I have already tried the package `nlesqlv`. The problem with this package is that, I could not specify a desired interval in which I want to check for the root.. In my case, I want to find the root in the interval of (-1, 1). In your example as well, the root came outside of this interval.

Comment: and one more thing, you and I wrote the same function. In two different ways that's all. But, I still think the way of writing the function is not correct. I think there is another way of writing the function, especially when it involves   summing over all the paired observations `(x, y)`. Thanks!

Comment: We did **not** write the same function. I believe I corrected your error(s); look at the equation you presented in your question. Take a good look and check with an example input. There is no solution between `-1` and `1`.  Draw a curve of the function and you can check it.

Comment: Let me put it in this way: Given my data, `f(-1) = -750.5601 and f(1) = 313.6238`. So, clearly there is(are) solution(s) in this interval. P. S. You are correct. I had put something different in my code earlier. I have changed it now.

Comment: I appreciate all of your efforts! Thanks a lot!

Comment: In my example `unitroot.all` does work as long as you do `fvec <- Vectorize(f)` and make the interval `c(-1,1.7)` and solve `fvec`.  `uniroot` from base R will also do the job.

Comment: `Vectorize` worked! Thank you!! I still have doubts on the writing of the function though!

Comment: Can you confirm whether you can run `curve(f, from = -10, to = 10)` on your code? Please let me know as I cannot run it on either of our codes. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes I can. Like this:  `fvec <- Vectorize(f)` followed by
`curve(fvec,-1,2.0)`